# Setting up private layer with local files in spacemacs

Tags: package, spacemacs, use-package

I'm trying to get the [unicode-math-input](https://github.com/tpapp/unicode-math-input) package up and running in spacemacs;
the package depends on [math-symbol-lists](https://github.com/vspinu/math-symbol-lists). Both packages are not featured in the official repositories.

From what I know about spacemacs I think I have to create a custom layer in
`.emacs.d/private/`. I called the layer `math` so I have the folder
`.emacs.d/private/math/` with two subfolders `math/local/unicode-math-input`
and `math/local/math-symbol-lists` (in which i cloned the respective github repositories).

The `.emacs.d/private/math/packages.el` file looks like this:

```
(defconst math-packages
  '(
    (math-symbol-lists :location local)
    (unicode-math-input :location local)

    (defun math/init-math ()
        (defun math/init-math-symbol-lists ()
            (use-package math-symbol-lists))

        (defun math/init-unicode-math-input ()
            (use-package unicode-math-input))
    )
   )
)
```

Further I added the layer to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`:

```
 dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
 '( 
  math
 )
```

Spacemacs starts without problem, however the input method `unicode-math-input` can't be selected with `M-x set-input-method`. What am I missing?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just went through the same process in order to create a layer. Only I needed to include one package only:

```
(setq math-packages '((math-symbol-lists :location local)))

(defun math/init-math-symbol-lists ()
  (use-package math-symbol-lists
    :init
    (progn
     ;; init commands
     )
    :config
    (progn
     ;; config commands (after init).
     )
))
```